# How do I stop this error message from occurring?

Tags: python

So I'm coding a discord bot that gives nice messages when it recognizes certain keywords, and users are able to add and delete their own messages. However, when I tried to delete a message on discord, the following response came from the bot:

```
ObservedList(value=["You're an amazing person.", 'You are amazing.', '"It's not who we are inside, but what we do that defines us." -Rachel Dawes, Batman Begins', 'You are amazing.', "You're the best person you can be.", 'You are an amazing person '])
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, as I'm following a video to make this bot, which can be viewed here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPTfmiYiuok

For reference, here is the range of code where I suspect there might be an error:

```
def delete_encouragement(index):
  encouragements = db["encouragements"]
  if len(encouragements) > index:
    del encouragements[index]
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements


    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
      print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
      if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
      msg = message.content
    
      if msg.startswith('+inspire'):
        quote = get_quote()
        await message.channel.send(quote)
    
      options = starter_encouragements
      if "encouragements" in db.keys():
        options = options + db["encouragements"].value
    
      if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(options))
    
      if msg.startswith('+new'):
        encouraging_message = msg.split("+new ",1)[1]
        update_encouragements(encouraging_message)
        await message.channel.send("New encouraging message added :)")
    
      if msg.startswith("+del"):
        encouragements = []
        if "encouragements" in db.keys():
          index = int(msg.split("+del",1)[1])
          delete_encouragement(index)
          encouragements = db["encouragements"]
          await message.channel.send(encouragements)
        
    
      if any(word in msg for word in happy_words):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(responses))
    
    
    client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your deletion branch after deleting particular encouragement from dictionary send out to chat remain encouragements. Try:

```
 if msg.startswith("+del"):
    encouragements = []
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      index = int(msg.split("+del",1)[1])
      delete_encouragement(index)
      encouragements = db["encouragements"]
```